# LeftStr() for UnicodeString type

Tags: c++builder, unicode-string

I'm moving some C++Builder code to BCB2010 and need to replace calls to `LeftStr()` and `RightStr()` with appropriate functions, as there's no `UnicodeString` overload of these.

`AnsiLeftStr()` appears to work, but the name is scaring me...

Answer (score 3):

You are right to be wary. Use the SubString method from UnicodeString instead.

Comment: Ansi...() actually have UnicodeString arguments and returns.  It seems really silly to not to have renamed or at least have Unicode...() counterparts to ease confusion.

Answer (score 3):

All of the `Ansi...()` functions were migrated to Unicode in CB2009.  The naming scheme was preserved to maintain backwards compatibility with pre-2009 code, that's all.

If you don't want to change your code to call `AnsiLeftStr()` instead of `LeftStr()`, then you could simply implement your own `LeftStr()` function that calls `AnsiLeftStr()` or `UnicodeString::SubString()` internally, eg:

```
UnicodeString __fastcall LeftStr(const UnicodeString &AText, const int ACount)
{
    return AnsiLeftStr(AText, ACount);
}
```

.

```
UnicodeString __fastcall LeftStr(const UnicodeString &AText, const int ACount)
{
    return AText.SubString(1, ACount);
}
```

Comment: Yes, [AnsiLeftStr](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/StrUtils.AnsiLeftStr) is the one to use.  [LeftStr](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/StrUtils.LeftStr) is in fact dangerous - it takes either an AnsiString or a WideString.  Be careful if you define your own to make sure yours is in scope and is called.

Comment: I would put the custom implementation in its own namespaces to avoid that problem.